How to define gesture recognizer in a DataTemplate Xaml which is defined as a resource?
We moved a few DataTemplates that were defined inline to application level ResourceDictionary as these could be used in multiple places in the application. However, the source code fails to build because the DataTemplates we moved had gesture recognizers defined.
I think we should be able to add the gesture recognizers through code behind, but wanted to check if there is a way to do it through Xaml, like it is done when DataTemplate is defined inline.
